# C++ Invalid Operands Error

Tags: c++

I am writing a program that calculates the slope of a line and displays it. I am getting the following error on pretty much all of these lines: "error: invalid operands of types âdouble(int, int, int, int)â and âintâ to binary âoperator*â". I'm not sure why it's not letting me multiply a double with an int. Help is appreciated.

```
 double figure_slope(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2)                                                                           
}
 (y1-y2)/(x1-x2);
}

void determine_line(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2)

{
if (figure_slope == 1 && y1 - figure_slope*x1 == 0)
cout << "Equation: x = " << x1 << endl;
else
if (figure_slope == 0 && y1 - figure_slope*x1 == 0)
  cout << "Equation: y = 0" << endl;
else
  if (figure_slope == 0)
    cout << "Equation: y = " << y1 - figure_slope*x1) << endl;
  else
    if (y1 - figure_slope*x1 == 0)
      cout << "Equation: y = " << figure_slope << "x" << endl;
    else
      if (y1 - figure_slope*x1 < 0)
        cout << "Equation: y = " << figure_slope << "x - " << -(y1 - figure_slope*x1) <<   endl;
      else
        cout << "Equation: y = " << figure_slope << "x + " << y1 - figure_slope*x1 << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`figure_slope` as you are using it is just a function pointer. You defined it to take parameters but aren't passing any in. You need to call it like `if (figure_slope(x1, y1, x2, y2) == 0 && ....`.

Also, `figure_slope()` is returning a double, but you are comparing against ints. This is probably not going to work as you expect.

Comment: Hi John, I called: figure_slope(int x1. int y1, int x2, int y2); . I'm getting the same errors as before as well as this one: error: expected primary-expression before âintâ on the line that I called figure_slope.

Comment: Call it like John3136 suggested

Comment: No: on the calls (all the `figure_slope`s in `determine_line()`) you don't need the `int`. i.e. just `figure_slope(x1, y1, x2, y2)` And really, if this answer (and @M2tMs) has not helped, you probably need to go back to the books for a while. This is trivial stuff you just have to know!

Comment: Ah, I see. I thought I only had to call it once, but I have to call it every time I use it. Thanks, I'm going through calling it each time I use it.

Comment: You can call it once and store the result. `double figureSlope = figure_slope(x1, y1, x2, y2);`

Comment: Thank you for all the help John. I'm no longer getting errors. Getting some wrong results, but I should be able to fix it from here. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

```
double figure_slope(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2)                                                                           
}
 (y1-y2)/(x1-x2);
}
```

You have an incorrect } brace on line 2.  It also needs to "return".  Beyond this, you need to cast each side to a double type if you want to have a floating point result.

Try the following instead:

```
double figure_slope(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2){
    return static_cast<double>(y1-y2)/static_cast<double>(x1-x2);
}
```

Beyond that when you call the function, you need to supply it with parameters.  Since you are going to be calling it with the same parameters in every place, you can just call it one time and assign the result to a value.  Try the following:

```
void determine_line(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2){
    double figureSlope = figure_slope(x1, y1, x2, y2);
    if(figureSlope == 1 && y1 - figureSlope*x1 == 0)
        cout << "Equation: x = " << x1 << endl;
    else if(figureSlope == 0 && y1 - figureSlope*x1 == 0)
        cout << "Equation: y = 0" << endl;
    else if(figureSlope == 0)
        cout << "Equation: y = " << y1 - figureSlope*x1) << endl;
    else if(y1 - figureSlope*x1 == 0)
        cout << "Equation: y = " << figureSlope << "x" << endl;
    else if(y1 - figureSlope*x1 < 0)
        cout << "Equation: y = " << figureSlope << "x - " << -(y1 - figureSlope*x1) << endl;
    else
        cout << "Equation: y = " << figureSlope << "x + " << y1 - figureSlope*x1 << endl;
}
```

Be aware that you are comparing ints to doubles in each of these cases, however.  You may need some more static_cast calls to ensure you get the results you expect.

Comment: Whoops. That's a mistake I made formatting on the submission. It's correct on my actual program.

Comment: Thanks M2tM. I called figure_slope and I'm not getting any errors. Now I just need to work out some issues in the semantics of the code.

Comment: Also we haven't learned static_cast yet, so I want to refrain from things we haven't covered, haha.

Comment: Casting only one of the arguments suffices, as the other will be promoted to `double` automatically.

Comment: static_cast is necessary.  "static_cast<double>(variable)" will convert "variable" from whatever type it is to a double if that conversion is legal.  You can use it to force an integer to divide as a double.  Old c-style casts exist as well "(double)variable" is an example, but you should use and familiarize yourself with the new cast semantics.